# How to download a Shell script from Github with Unix formatting?

Tags: shell, unix, github

I am trying to share a Shell script from my Github with people. It is for a workshop and I thought the easiest way would be to have them download it with:

```
wget https://raw.githubusercontent.com/user/repo/master/script.sh
```

But I am getting this when I try to run it:

```
script.sh: line 2: $'\r': command not found
script.sh: line 4: $'\r': command not found
script.sh: line 6: $'\r': command not found
script.sh: line 7: syntax error near unexpected token `$'\r''
'cript.sh: line 7: `helpFunction()
```

However, it works when I convert it to Unix with dos2unix using:

```
dos2unix script.sh
```

How can I avoid having to use this extra step? I am also open to other suggestions about sharing my code in a simple way.

Comment: Can you post a real URL?

Comment: `dos2unix` is the way to solve this problem unless you have a way to make the windows newline customer compatible with unix newline character.